# Xcode - Dragged in same image twice and it is listed twice, why? Is deleting one of these images a risk?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've noticed that if you drag into Xcode the same image twice, then it is duplicated in the project navigator view*. It other words, it is listed twice.

Two questions:

1. Why does this happen? - shouldn't there be a warning?
2. If I delete the reference** to one of these files to have the project navigator view only list the image once, does this present some sort of risk? Am I not deleting a reference to the same file?***

*The column typically furthest left in Xcode which contains a list of files within the project

**via a right click on one of the image files -> then hitting the delete option -> then selecting "Remove Reference"

***deleting the reference only removes one of the files, the other file remains.

Comment: Please see my answer to really understand what is happening in your case. It is important to understand the why behind things along your journey as an iOS developer. Good luck!

Comment: Note that if you catch the error soon enough you can do Ctrl-Z to reverse the action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project file holds a list of references to files. Those files might be in your local project folder, or anywhere else.

Drag the same file in twice, with the option to copy to the project folder, and the second time you'll get an error. You can't have two files in the same folder with the same name. But there's is no such restriction on references to files. They are simply entries in a list in your project file.

So if you drag a file without also moving it, you are only creating a reference.

Yes, when you right click on one of these references and select delete, then you get the choice to remove the reference only, or to also move the referenced file to the trash.  Removing the reference only is perfectly safe.  The file will be untouched, and the other reference to the file will still be valid.

Comment: Great answer, also if you are looking to research this a little further I would recommend opening your xcode project with a text editor and looking at the difference. There should be some reference tags you can see change:)

Comment: And to be perfectly sure, one can RMB on the file in the project navigator and select "Show in Finder".  This will show the directory containing the file and you can see if there is one or two.  Also, you can do this on two "duplicate" files in the navigator, to see if they refer to the same file or a different one.

Answer (score 1):

To understand why this is happening you need to understand the options you have when adding a file. When adding an image or file to your project you can enable or disable the following option:

**Copy items into destinations group's folder (if needed)**

So what does this mean exactly? By selecting (checking) this option you are making a copy of the original file into the Xcode project group folder. Now when you call the file from your source you are reference the file you copied into your Project group folder. The original file, wherever that may be(desktop) remains untouched.

**Note - What does the "if needed" qualifier mean?**

If the file already exists in the project group folder then the file will not be copied into the folder. Simply a reference will be added to the project navigator. If this does not make sense then I will give you a practical example. Say you create a bunch of images and add them directly to the project folder. What I mean is you drag and drop them into the Xcode project folder using finder(not via Xcode). At this point you have added the files to the project, but if you open the Xcode project you will notice that you do not see a reference to the file in the navigator. So this is a case where the if needed qualifier will be triggered. You still need to add the reference to the file as you normally would by adding it via Xcode. But this time just the reference is made and no file is copied into the Project Folder because it already exists.

**What happens if you leave the option unchecked?**

Xcode will create a reference to the file but will **not** create a copy of the file and add it to the project. The reference in your Xcode project will be point to the original location of your file wherever that may be. This is not recommended unless you know why and you need to do this because if you accidentally delete the original file then the reference to the file will be broken. You will know when this happens because the file reference in Xcode will be displayed in red.

Now back to your case. What happened in your situation is that you added the file to your project with the option unchecked. This will create a reference to the file in Xcode with actually moving the file into the project. The second time you add it into your project you are creating a new reference to the file but you are not actually performing any file operations like moving or copying so that is why you are not presented with an error.

I suggest always leaving the option above checked. This way you will know if you adding a duplicated file to your project. Also you do not breaking any references to your file at some point in the future. Hope this helps you understand the why behind things a bit more.

Comment: Thank you for the detail. However, xCode doesn't give me a warning if I drag a file that is already in that project's xCode folder and already referenced. It just lists it twice. This seems to contradict your point in the 2nd last paragraph. I'm using xCode 4.6.2

Comment: I edited the bottom portion of my answer. That could be because, you added the file with the option unchecked. If you add the file with the option unchecked it simply adds a reference to the file. It does not create a copy or add a new file anywhere. Therefore no error is thrown. Technically you can add the reference as many times as you want since it is not actually performing any file operations. I know this is not a common thing to do but that is the reason behind it.

Comment: I have the add file if needed checked.